How can I use decorators to modify the behavior of multiple functions?
I’m learning about decorators in Python and would like to use them to modify the behaviour of several more complex functions in my code. Specifically, I want to:

Log the execution time for each function.
Handle and log any errors that occur during function execution.

Here's an example of one of my functions, which processes a list of numbers, filters out the even numbers, and computes the sum of the remaining odd numbers:
def my_function(numbers):
    odd_numbers = [n for n in numbers if n % 2 != 0]
    result = sum(odd_numbers)
    return result

I also have another function that processes a string by reversing the words in the sentence:
def reverse_sentence(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    reversed_sentence = ' '.join(reversed(words))
    return reversed_sentence

I understand how to create a simple decorator, but how do I create a decorator that:

Logs the execution time of each function.
Catches and logs any errors that occur during function execution.

I would like to apply this decorator to both of these functions (and potentially others). Any help with an example would be greatly appreciated!

Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! The [tour] and [ask] are great places to check out as you find your bearings here.

There are modules available for logging and error handling. what have you tried so far ?

How would you know if an error has occurred? What constitutes an "error"?

@SIGHUP I imagine they mean it catches any unhandled exceptions.

Maybe this example would help:
import time

def measure_function(f):
    def execute(*args, **kwargs):
        t = time.time()
        try:
            res = f(*args, **kwargs)
            print("function %s cost %s seconds" % (f.__name__, time.time()-t))
            return res
        except Exception as error:
            print("function %s failed with error: %s" % (f.__name__, error))
    return execute

@measure_function
def my_function(numbers):
    odd_numbers = [n for n in numbers if n % 2 != 0]
    result = sum(odd_numbers)
    return result


print(my_function([1,2,3,5,6,7,8]))


@measure_function
def reverse_sentence(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    reversed_sentence = ' '.join(reversed(words))
    return reversed_sentence

print(reverse_sentence("Logs the execution time of each function"))


Your decorator prints the function address which does not seem useful. Were you expecting the function name? Use f.__name__ to get this.

Check out f-strings, they're awesome.

@user19077881 You were right, thx.

If you want to record timings and also catch, report and re-raise exceptions then you could do this:
from functools import wraps
from time import perf_counter
from pathlib import Path

ERROR_FILE = Path("except.txt")
TIMING_FILE = Path("timing.txt")

def my_wrapper(func):
    def report(path: Path, message: str | Exception):
        try:
            with path.open("a") as p:
                print(f"{func.__name__} {message}", file=p)
        except Exception:
            pass

    @wraps(func)
    def wrap_(*args, **kwargs):
        start = perf_counter()
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            report(ERROR_FILE, e)
            raise e
        finally:
            duration = perf_counter() - start
            report(TIMING_FILE, f"{duration=:.4f}")

    return wrap_


@my_wrapper
def afunc():
    raise ValueError("That didn't work!")


@my_wrapper
def bfunc(x):
    print(x)


try:
    afunc()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

bfunc(99)

Output to stdout:
That didn't work!
99

Last line of except.txt
afunc That didn't work!

Example of last 2 lines of timing.txt
afunc duration=0.0002
bfunc duration=0.0000


Would try: finally: make this a bit cleaner, so you don't need to re-raise the exception by hand?

@AKX I have to catch the exception in order to report it. So, surely, I have no option but to re-raise it. You will almost certainly have a superior solution. Once you've posted your answer I'll delete this
